# Need my code to count each words position number and store to file

Tags: python

I need to develop a program on python that identifies individual words in a sentence and stores them in a list but stores a word's position number in the sentence not the actual word. I have developed this code yet cannot get it to save the words position.

```
 sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
 keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
 words = sentence.split(' ')

 for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if keyword == word:
        print(i+1)

 file = open("newfile.txt","a")
 file.write(input("text to write in the file")+"/n")
 file.close()
```

Anyone got any advice, pointers or help?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output

Comment: what you are asking and doing in program are very very different.

Comment: Note that your indention is broken. The secode, third line and the `for ...` have to be on the same indention level as the first line. The `if ...` is supposed to get executed on every iteration of the loop, so it has to be indented one level. The last three line don't fit your description, so I'm not sure how they are indented properly. The `"/n"`is probably meant to be a newline and therefore should be a `"\n"`instead. And, finally, the `enter code here`should be a comment (preceded by a `#`) on its very own line.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you question and the code snippet, I have come to a conclusion that your program,

- Accept **sentence** from user
- Get a **keyword** from user
- If the **word** in **sentence** matches the **keyword**, save the **word number** in file.

So, for that, Here's the code.

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
words = sentence.split(' ')

file=open("newfile.txt","a") #open the file in append mode

for i, word in enumerate(words):
  if keyword == word:
    file.write(str(i+1)+" ") #append the text. I've added space to distiguish digit.
file.close() #Close the file after loop.
```